# Android app calculating its own MD5 checksum

Tags: java, android, md5, checksum

How can an android app calculate its own md5 checksum when already installed? Tried googling but all results were about another app calculating others' checksums.

Comment: youbcan give each user a unique version of software... but why dont u make a file type manager instead that encrypts headers and corrupts files intelligibly with its own filespace server lookup.

Answer (score 9):

How would that be useful? To compare with something, the expected checksum needs to be in the APK. But if someone changed your APK (repackaged, etc.), they can also easily change the expected value as well. You could get it from a server, but it's not too hard to disable this as well if they are messing with your package.

Additionally, some tools will patch the code in Dalvik cache directly and thus change what your app does without ever touching the APK.

Generally, you just get the path to the APK, read as binary and calculate using `MessageDigest`. You can use the `PackageManager` to get app info and then [ApplicationInfo#sourceDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#sourceDir) gives you the location of the package. BTW, this might not work with paid apps on JB (4.1 and later), because you don't have permission to read the actual APK (this is the result of 'forward locking', aka 'app encryption').

Comment: well, I am interested in writing a library for a bunch of apps I am developing that basically calls home for license validation and what not. it'll pass the IMEI, app id, app version, apk checksum etc, which is all passed to the class when the initial Activity is instantiated. the web side would then compare the checksum passed to othe one expected for the passed version. if they don't match, it may be assumed the package was tampered with (perhaps pirated?)

Comment: I can be pirated without being tampered with. And also patched without changing the APK (cf. Lucky Patcher). And how will you know the IMEI? What if the device is WiFi only? Generally not an easy task. You might want to look into Google's LVL, although it has it's own problems.

Comment: It can certainly be useful as Whiskey mentioned. For developers looking to curtail cheating on online leaderboards, having the app send a hashsum to the server in addition to pushing scores means that it's a failsafe method for preventing apk tampering, even if it would still succumb to dynamic hacks